Can't send text message on USB GSM modem over 30 characters CMS 69 error Node JS
I'm trying to send a text message on a USB GSM modem connected to my computer. I've got a few SIM cards, some are PAYG, others are Pay monthly. Regardless of the SIM, both can send a text message under 30 characters, but I've noticed some strange behaviour.
Since September 1st, anything over 30 characters regardless of the message fails to send on the contract SIM, whereas the PAYG sim always works.
More bizarely, trying to send the following on the contract SIM, being under 30 characters:
".com" -> works
".com/foo" -> fails to send
I'm getting a CMS error 69 reported back from the cell tower, so have tried a different cell tower with no luck. Tried roaming, different devices, actual phone instead of modem.
What am I missing?
let serialportgsm = require('serialport-gsm')

let modem = serialportgsm.Modem()
let options = {
    baudRate: 115200,
    dataBits: 8,
    stopBits: 1,
    parity: 'none',
    rtscts: false,
    xon: false,
    xoff: false,
    xany: false,
    autoDeleteOnReceive: true,
    enableConcatenation: true,
    incomingCallIndication: true,
    incomingSMSIndication: true,
    pin: '',
    customInitCommand: '',
    cnmiCommand: 'AT+CNMI=2,1,0,2,1',
    logger: console
}

modem.open('COM', options, {})

modem.on('open', data => {
    modem.initializeModem((data) => {

        // doesn't send
        modem.sendSMS('+447838484858', 'This is a long text message with some link https://example.com/', false, (data) => {
            console.log('sent!')
        })
    })
})

